# Importing Multiple Excel Files using OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to read in multiple excel files and append the data from each file into one master file. Each file will have the same headers (So I can skip the import of the first row after the initial file).

I am pretty new to both Python and the OpenPyXL module. I am able to import the first workbook without problem. My problem comes in when I need to open the subsequent file and copy the data to paste into the original worksheet.

Here is my code so far:

```
# Creating blank workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Read in excel data
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('first_file.xlsx') #explicitly loading workbook, will automate later

# grab active worksheet in current workbook
ws = wb.active

#get max columns and rows
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
print ("Rows: ", sheet.max_row) # for debugging purposes
print ("Columns: ", sheet.max_column) # for debugging purposes
last_data_point = ws.cell(row = sheet.max_row, column = sheet.max_column).coordinate
print ("Last data point in current worksheet:", last_data_point) #for debugging purposes

#import next file and add to master
append_point = ws.cell(row = sheet.max_row + 1, column = 1).coordinate
print ("Start new data at:", append_point)
wb = load_workbook('second_file.xlsx')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
start = ws.cell(coordinate='A2').coordinate
print("New data start: ", start)
end = ws.cell(row = sheet2.max_row, column = sheet2.max_column).coordinate
print ("New data end: ", end)

# write a value to selected cell
#sheet[append_point] = 311
#print (ws.cell(append_point).value)

#save file
wb.save('master_file.xlsx')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your code. It looks too complicated. When copying between worksheets you probably want to use `ws.rows`.

```
wb1 = load_workbook('master.xlsx')
ws2 = wb1.active

for f in files:
    wb2 = load_workbook(f)
    ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']
    for row in ws2.rows[1:]:
          ws1.append((cell.value for cell in row))
```

Comment: This did the trick nicely. I defined files as an array of filenames and changed ws1 to ws, since I had not defined ws1 elsewhere. I had to make some other small edits, but overall I understood what you were doing. The dates did come across in a different format than the original, i.e. "Custom" instead of "Date" format. Is there an easy way to fix that problem without overcomplicating it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but there is no "Date" format. All dates and times use more or less custom formatting. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: Yes it is a separate issue. What I mean is that it comes across as 2015-09-01 0:00:00 instead of 9/1/2015. Essentially it comes across in Long Date format instead of Short Date format. This is not a big problem though.

Comment: Excel uses number formatting to distinguish between numbers and dates and times and this is locale specific. openpyxl defaults to ISO format. to be unambiguous. You'll need to provide an explicit format if you want something else.

Answer (score -1):

you can just use : wb = load_workbook('master.xlsx') with this you can access multiple workbooks by simply making an var e.g wb2 = load_workbook("master2.xlsx"). Now for accessing a sheet inside a workbook : wd = wb["Sheetname"]. Like this now you can edit it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).